# Strip prefix and value

Tags: c#

if I have the string "freq1" or "freq12" and so on, how can I strip out freq and also the number by itself?

Answer (score 3):

```
string foo     = "freq12";
string fooPart = foo.Substring(4);   // "12"
int fooNumber  = int.parse(fooPart); // 12
```

if the "freq" part is not constant, then you can use regular expressions:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = @"([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)";
string foo = "freq12";

Match match = Regex.Match(foo, pattern);

string fooPart = match.Groups[1].Value;
int fooNumber  = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
```

Comment: number varies in length, so don't think yours will work because you're betting on a fixed length here (4)

Comment: Neither of his solutions expects the number portion to be fixed in length.  The first merely expects a 4 char prefix before a number.  The second merely expects some letter before some digits.

Comment: Yeah, the RegEx solution added in the edit works generically (for any length of text/number parts). See my solution for a non-regex approach.

Comment: your regex could maybe be replaced with: [^\d]+(\d+)

Comment: @Svish: You're right, and that was the first regex I thought of, but then I thought the OP might not want whitespaces and changed my regex.

Answer (score 2):

Is it always going to be the text *freq* that prepends the number within the string? If so, your solution is very simple:

```
var str = "freq12";
var num = int.Parse(str.Substring(4));
```

**Edit:** Here's a more generic method in the case that the first part of the string isn't always "freq".

```
var str = "freq12";
int splitIndex;

for(splitIndex = 0; splitIndex < str.Length; splitIndex++)
{
    if (char.IsNumeric(str[splitIndex]))
        break;
}

if (splitIndex == str.Length)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The input string does not contain a numeric part.");

var textPart = int.Parse(str.Substring(0, splitIndex));
var numPart = int.Parse(str.Substring(splitIndex));
```

In the given example, `textPart` should evaluate to *freq* and `numPart` to *12*. Let me know if this still isn't what you want.

Comment: >>>Is it always going to be the text freq that prepends the number within the string?

yes

Comment: Then unless I'm mistaken, you seem to have your answer. (Can Berk Güder has suggested the same solution) :)

Comment: you are betting it on a fixed string length though

Comment: damn tried this:

                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selection))
                    selectionType = selection.Substring(0);
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(selection) )
                    int selectedValue = int.Parse(selection.Substring(1));

the value for selection is "f3"

Comment: this does not work, I get invalid embedded statement parse
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selection))
                    selectionType = selection.Substring(0);
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(selection) )
                    int selectedValue = int.Parse(selection.Substring(0));

Comment: Post is updated. I've provided a non-regex solution which to me is slightly simpler (and certainly quicker).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String oldString = "freq1";
String newString = oldString.Replace("freq", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the word "freq" will always be there, then you can do something like:

```
string number = "freq1".Replace("freq","");
```

That will result in "1".